# URL works in Postman but not in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a URL that works in POSTMAN

https://proxyec8-ee0278a83.dispatcher.eu2.hana.ondemand.com/sposea-qac/sap/opu/odata/SPOSEA/BPM_ODATA_HANA_V1_SRV/

but when I use the same code in node js it does not work:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch'),
      express = require('express'),
      app = express();
async function makeRequest(url, config) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, config)
    return {
      status: response.status,
      payload: await response.json(),
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return {
      status: null,
      payload: error.message,
    }
  }
}

let url =
  "https://proxyec8-ee0278a83.dispatcher.eu2.hana.ondemand.com/sposea-qac/sap/opu/odata/SPOSEA/BPM_ODATA_HANA_V1_SRV/"
const config = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: { 
    Authorization: 'Basic '+'TUtBTk46SGFuYUAxOTg5',
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
}
let response = await makeRequest(url, config)
return response
```

Not sure why it is not working in node but the same url works in POSTMAN. Could you help.

```
Response:
{"status":401,"payload":{}}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors? What does the response body say?

Comment: Your URL seems to require a login. Where/How are you providing them when requesting it through Node?

Comment: @Leia: It says unauthorized

Comment: @Sawant: I edited the code with Authorization

Answer (score 1):

Fixed - Due to certificate issues in the back end .